# Angular 2 return data from arrow function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code

```
getEnquiryWithId(id: number) {
    let enquiryStore = this.db.transaction('enquiries', 'readonly').objectStore('enquiries');
    let index = enquiryStore.index('enquiries');
    let request = index.get(id);
    return request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      return event.target.result;
    }
  }
```

which i'm trying to use in a pipe

```
transform(value: number): string {
    let request = this.dbStore.getEnquiryWithId(value);
    let result = request();
  }
```

I get an error saying `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature`.

> Note: that I cannot rely RxJs subjects here as my transform function needs to return something, as its a pipe. How do I make this work?

Comment: What are you expecting `request()` to do? `getEnquiryWithId` doesn't return anything you could possibly call. You could e.g. make `getEnquiryWithId` return an Observable that the pipe could then `.map` and use an additional `| async` to resolve it.

Comment: i want the `event.target.result` accessible in `transform`

Comment: I understand that, but it's not clear why you thought calling `request()` would do that. You need to do this asynchronously - a pipe *can* return an observable, you just put e.g. `startingPoint | myPipe | async` in the template to resolve it. But `getEnquiryWithId` will have to return an observable, or something you can turn into one. The error message is because it returns nothing at all, but you're still trying to call what it returns.

Comment: i understood your point, but how am I supposed to return anything from `getEnquiryWithId`? Also I have edited the question as it was missing a return statement.

Comment: You should return a `Promise` that resolves when `onsuccess` is called.

Comment: You can't return anything other than a Promise oran Observable, i.e. something that represents a future, asynchronously obtained result. You can't return the result itself. Transforming an asynchronous process to a synchronous one is not possible.

Comment: I see, as @GünterZöchbauer pointed out. Do I put the `onsuccess` event in the `Promise`'s resolve section?

Comment: Side note: It does seem very wise to make a DB query from within a pipe. As per [the doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#an-impure-caching-pipe): "Let's write one more impure pipe, a pipe that makes an HTTP request to the server. Normally, that's a horrible idea. It's probably a horrible idea no matter what we do. "

Comment: Its not making http calls. Its querying local indexeddb

Answer (score 0):

The title misleading. You don't want data to be returned from an arrow function (which is trivially possible), but you want your arrow function to be synchronously executed - which is not possible as it's a callback that will be called by the JS engine.

As others mentioned you can return a Promise in your function that resolves as soon as the the inner query succeeds:

```
getEnquiryWithId(id: number) {
  let enquiryStore = this.db.transaction('enquiries', 'readonly').objectStore('enquiries');
  let index = enquiryStore.index('enquiries');
  let request = index.get(id);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      resolve(event.target.result);
    };
    request.onerror = (event) => {
      reject(request.errorCode);
    };
  }
}
```

If you want to display the result of a promise you could simply use `AsyncPipe`. It's not necessary to write an own transform function.